# In shells, how to find a file in current directory with at least 2 characters but not contain cs by using echo

Tags: bash, shell, echo

In shells, how to find a file in current directory whose name has at least 2 characters but not contain   cs by using echo.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
$ find . -name "*??*" -not -name "*cs*"
```

If you are interested only in the files in the current directry, and don't want to traverse to subdirectories, try the following.

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*??*" -not -name "*cs*"
```